# Theming Material Design in HTML/ CSS

Tags: html, css, material-design, themes

I have been spending the last few hours trying to find a way to change the primary/ secondary colour of the standard Material Design colour scheme (Purple).

I have tried overriding through the main css file to no avail.

Any guidance as to how this can be done would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Edit:
The style and script files are being imported from the following:
https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js
https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to better help you, would you please update your question to contain all relevant code in a [minimal, complete & verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Additionally, providing screenshots of the problem and details of what you’ve tried, make it much more likely that you’ll get a useful answer. 

For further information, please refer to the help article regarding **[how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what Material Design package you're using, the tech stack, etc.

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the feedback. I am using the non-lite version with the libraries being imported from the following:
https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css
https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js

I understand these are the ones recommended by MD themselves.

Comment: How is this related to `PHP`?

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the color scheme of the Material Design package before you download it [here](https://getmdl.io/customize/).

Otherwise, the Github package is built using SCSS and CSS variables. These are specified in `_color-definitions.scss` but you'll need to rebuild the project files if you change them.

[Material Theme builder](https://material-theme-builder.glitch.me/) will tell you exactly which variables to update, where to find them and even give you a preview.

Comment: I am getting the style file from here:
https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css
I was hoping to override the values of that.

Comment: You can still use a [theme builder](https://material-theme-builder.glitch.me/) to modify it and you'll still need to update variables and rebuild the relevant files.